# how to reverse char array by strrev() function

Tags: c++

i am using strrev() function to reverse a char array and get output.
 but it shows strange results.If I enters "madam" and it's reverse it results  like this.

[image: this is image of error]

kindly explain me about error.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

main(){

    int x,i;
    cout<<"Enter the size of array:";
    cin>>x;
    cout<<"Enter "<< x <<" elements in array:";
    char ch1[x] ;
    for(i=0; i<x; i++){
        cin>>ch1[i];
    }
    char ch2[x] = {0};

    for(i=0; i<x; i++){
    ch2[i] = ch1[i];
    }

    cout<<"Copied array is:";
    for(i=0; i<x; i++){
        cout<<ch2[i];
    }

    cout<<endl;
    strrev(ch2);
    cout<<ch2;

    if(ch1[x] == ch2[x]){
        cout<<"\nPalindrom";
    }else{
        cout<<"\nNot palindrom";
    }


}
```

Comment: this is the code also rekeb mazharul

Comment: `chN[x]` is actually a segfault

Comment: You should be aware that `char ch1[x];` is a GCC extension in C++.  A portable solution which still has your problem `std::vector<char> ch1(x);`  (you then need to pass `&ch[0]` to `strrev`).  Alternatively, use `std::string`, and your problem will go away.

Comment: Aside from your question, which is adequately answered below, note that you are only checking one character. E.g. entering "mabcm" will also report 'Palindrom' (after you fixed the null terminator issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to null terminate your c-style strings, something like:

```
char ch1[x + 1];  // need space for null
for(i=0; i<x; i++){
    cin>>ch1[i];
}
ch1[x] = '\0';  // null terminate

char ch2[x + 1] = {0};  // need space for null here too

for(i=0; i<x; i++){
ch2[i] = ch1[i];
}
ch2[x] = '\0';  // null terminate
```

Comment: `ch1[x] = '\0';` is going to end in tears.  With the example, it will write to the sixth element of `ch1` - and there are only five of them.

Comment: @MartinBonner `ch1` is fine, but `ch2` isn't -- edited answer accordingly

Comment: Surely you need `char ch2[x+1] = {0}` too?

Comment: @MartinBonner Yes, that's what I fixed.  Please see edited answer.

Comment: When I looked, there was no `x+1`.  <shrug> - Browser caches?  Sorry for the noise.

Comment: @MartinBonner Not noise, without your input my answer would've been incorrect -- Thanks :) )

Answer (score 0):

The function [strrev](http://fresh2refresh.com/c-programming/c-strings/c-strrev-function/) needs a string, but you have a char vector. You have to insert the **null-terminator '\0'** at the end of the vector in order to use the function!

Comment: An alternative is to use std::reverse to reverse the char vector.